# Swift : Multiple results from Dictionary in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

Is it possible to create a search bar in swift where the user is searching through a dictionary in a way that the user can either be typing in elements of list or the key itself and the search bar will only return the key?

In other words, considering this dictionary :

```
let dict  = [  "primes" : [2,3,5,7] , 
               "even" : [2,4,6,8 ] ,
               "odd" : [1,3,5,7] , 
               "fib" : [1,1,2,3,5]
            ]
```

if the user types in 7 the search bar will return primes and odd

if the user types in odd the search bar will return odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textDidChange` delegate function from `UISearchBarDelegate` will be triggered when ever user type something in the searchbar. 
in this function you can write your filter code.

Here's below an example based on a Dictionary. The results in this example are the dictionary keys.

```
var filtered:[String] = []

let dict  = [ "primes" : [2,3,5,7] , "even" : [2,4,6,8 ] , "odd" : [1,3,5,7] , "fib" : [1,1,2,3,5] ]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchBar.delegate = self
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    // just to reset the array and result text
    filtered = []
    textView.text  = ""

    _ = dict.filter {
        let key = $0;
        _ = $1.filter {
            if ($0 == Int(searchText)) {
                filtered.append(key)
            }
            return true
        }
        return true
    }

    // show results
    textView.text = filtered.description
}
```

Comment: @tanc-27 Is that helpful for you?